# Configuring website with cPanel not to show a directory index listing

Tags: web-development, cpanel, navigation

I developed a web page and uploaded it to the web with cPanel, the problem is that when I search for it in Google, it comes out with a name and a "raw" summary that says "Name Last Modified Size Directory cgi-bin"

[image: Image of my problem]

I have very little knowledge about this platform; could you help me configure this?

Comment: Please dont post an image when its text information

Comment: The only time I had that was when my host company had not deployed the certificate properly.  Do you have  security certificate

Comment: You don't need to configure anything - Google will eventually reindex it and it will work.   You may be able to ask Google to reindex your site as the content has change. That said, your site is using http - you should add a redirection from http to https.

Comment: I know this doesn't solve your question, but if you aren't using cgi-bin you can delete that directory

Comment: @davidgo "You don't need to configure anything" - That's assuming the name of the file the OP used to develop their web page is a `DirectoryIndex` document.

Comment: "I developed a web page" - what is the name of this file? What happens when you click the link in the Google search results?

Comment: @mrwhite - no. Its because I went to the URL showed in the image (and indexed in 2021) and it responded with a web page.

Comment: @davidgo Yes, it is; given the information in the question (which is all we can reasonably go off). But please put your answer as an "answer", rather than a comment. Otherwise we might as well just close/delete the question.